# Visa Initial Entry Date (IED)

Tags: visa, australia

Each visa granted includes the following visa condition:

> 8504       The holder must enter Australia as the holder of the visa
>   to which the condition applies before a date specified by the
>   Minister.

Its very important for me to know whether one can arrive in Australia exactly on the IED date, or should be there a day before?

Answer (score 1):

You can arrive exactly on the same day before midnight, i.e. before the day changes at the local port of arrival. If still in doubt, your grant pdf should have a phone number or an email address and you can contact the department and have this clarified.